# Pytorch - Selecting n indices without replacement from dimension x

Tags: pytorch

Suppose I have the following embeddings `emb_user = torch.randn(64, 128, 256)`. From the second dimension (of length 128), I wish to pick out 16 at random at each instance. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing the following:

```py
idx = torch.multinomial(torch.ones(64, 128), 16)
sampled_emb_user = emb_user[torch.arange(len(emb_user)).unsqueeze(-1), idx]
```

What I also find curios is that the above multinomial would not work if the weight matrix (`torch.ones(64, 128)`) exceeded more than 2 dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in your case you want an uniform distribution you could speed it up with

```py
idx = torch.sort(torch.randint(
    0, 128 - 15, (64, 16), device=device
), axis=1).values + torch.arange(0, 16, device=device).reshape(1, -1)
sampled_emb_user = emb_user[torch.arange(len(emb_user)).unsqueeze(-1), idx]
```

Instead of

```py
idx = torch.multinomial(torch.ones(64, 128, device=device), 16)
sampled_emb_user = emb_user[torch.arange(len(emb_user)).unsqueeze(-1), idx]
```

The runtimes on my machine are `427 µs` and `784 µs` with `device='cpu'`; `135 µs` and `260 µs` and `469 µs` with `device='cuda'`.

How it works?

The sorted randint gives the indices for a multinomial distribution with replacement. That is increasing, adding the `arange` term makes it strictly increasing, thus eliminates the replacements.

Illustrating with a small case

```py
idx = torch.sort(torch.randint(0, 7, (4,))).values
print('Indices with replacement in the range from 0 to 6: ', idx)
print('Indices without replacement in the slice: ', idx + torch.arange(4))
```

```txt
Indices with replacement in the range from 0 to 6:  tensor([0, 5, 5, 6])
Indices without replacement in the slice:  tensor([0, 6, 7, 9])
```

A possibly faster solution, but not from exactly the same distribution is the following:

```py
idx = torch.cumsum(torch.diff(
torch.sort(torch.randint(
    0, 128 - 16, (64, 17), device=device
), axis=1).values
, axis=1) + 1, axis=1) - 1
sampled_emb_user = emb_user[torch.arange(len(emb_user)).unsqueeze(-1), idx]
```

One more way, I expect to be closer to the exact method, not very rigorously analyzed.

```py
# 1-rand() to include 1 and exclude zero.
d = torch.cumsum(1 - torch.rand(64, 17, device=device
), axis=1)
# this produces a sorted tensor with values in the range [0:128-16]
d = (((128 - 15) * d[:, :-1]) / d[:, -1:]).to(torch.long)
idx = d + torch.arange(0, 16, device=device).reshape(1, -1)
```

But in the end it tends to be slower than the method using sort.

Comment: This is brilliant!!! For the first solution, can we take out the sort? Or is that important. And for the second one why do you say its not the same distribution. Happy to read a link if you got one.

Comment: Yes, the sort is required, you need to know the order of the samples in order to determine which items are affected by the replacement. But I think that is not worth changing, in my machine the bottle neck is gathering the embeddings.
The last one is skips the first item, I added one more variation that does not have that problem, who knows in your environment it will be better. 
I am sorry, I don't have references for these tricks.